# Regarding the general method of the ''Classify groups of order $X$'' question.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product

Anyone who has had to prepare for an algebra qualifying exam is familiar with the "Classify groups of order $X$" question.

To illustrate my general question, which I postpone until the end, consider the following simple example in which I classify groups $G$ of order $3 \cdot 7$.  Let $H$ and $K$ be the $7$- and $3$-Sylow subgroups, respectively.  By Sylow's theorems, we find easily that $H$ is normal and $K$ is either normal or one of seven conjugate copies.  Also $H \cong \mathbf{Z}_7$ and $K \cong \mathbf{Z}_3$.  Let $x$ be a generator of $\mathbf{Z}_3$ and let $y$ be a generator of $\mathbf{Z}_7$, both viewed multiplicatively.  Now $G$ is a semidirect product of $H$ and $K$, hence the possible structures of $G$ are determined by the possible group homomorphisms $$ \mathbf{Z}_3 \to \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbf{Z}_7) \cong \mathbf{Z}_6. $$  Such a group homomorphism is determined by the image of $x$; since the order of this image must divide the order of $x$, we see $x$ is either sent to the identity automorphism $\mathbf{1}$ or an automorphism of order three.

We find that a generator of $\mathbf{Z}_6$ is the automorphism $\alpha \colon y \mapsto y^3$.  Therefore, there are three possible group homomorphisms, determined by sending $x$ to $\mathbf{1}$, to $\alpha^2 \colon y \mapsto y^2$, or to $\alpha^4 \colon y \mapsto y^4$.  It follows there are at most three possible groups of order $21$, generated by $x$ and $y$ and subject to the relations $x^3 = x^7 = 1$ as well as one of the following commutativity relations: $$xy = yx, \;\;\;\;\; xy = y^2 x, \;\;\;\;\; xy = y^4 x. $$  All such groups exist by employing the abstract construction of the semidirect product.

What follows is always the most subtle part of the analysis.

> Which of these groups are duplicates?

The first is the case $G \cong \mathbf{Z}_3 \times \mathbf{Z}_7$ which is clearly distinct from the remaining two.  Let the second group be denoted $G_2$ and the third $G_4$.  If $G_2$ were isomorphic to $G_4$, then there would have to exist $X, Y \in G_4$ of orders three and seven, respectively, and satisfying $XY = Y^2 X$ (or $X, Y \in G_2$ satisfying $XY = Y^4 X$).  And it is easy to see that, in fact, this condition is sufficient for $x \mapsto X$, $y \mapsto Y$ to determine an isomorphism $G_2 \cong G_4$.  Note that both $G_2$ and $G_4$ have seven $3$-Sylow subgroups (otherwise they would be Cartesian products).  So there are $14$ candidates for $X$ and $6$ candidates for $Y$.

Morally, at least in my opinion, these groups should be isomorphic, because the only difference in their definition occurs when we chose between the two generators $\alpha^2$ and $\alpha^4$ of the cyclic subgroup $\mathbf{Z}_3 \subset \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbf{Z}_7) \cong \mathbf{Z}_6$, and these generators are 'essentially the same'.

This is indeed the case, but the proof feels 'lucky'.  One finds by calculation that no map of the form $X = x$ and $Y = y^k$ satisfies $XY = Y^2 X \in G_4$.  But this is satisfied by taking $X = x^2$ and $Y = y$:  $$X Y = x^2 y = x y^4 x = y^{16} x^2 = y^2 x^2 = Y^2 X \in G_4. $$  We conclude there are two groups of order $21$ up to isomorphism.

To give an example of how this problem becomes more complex, if instead one were computing groups of order $3 \cdot 7 \cdot 13$, then one must determine group homomorphisms $$\mathbf{Z}_3 \to \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbf{Z}_7 \times \mathbf{Z}_{13}) \cong \mathbf{Z}_6 \times \mathbf{Z}_{12}. $$  (Don't forget that the automorphisms of the direct product is the direct product of the automorphisms when the orders of the groups are coprime!)  If $\alpha$ generates $\mathbf{Z}_6$ and $\beta$ generates $\mathbf{Z}_{12}$, then there are nine possible semidirect structures, corresponding to $x$ being sent to to any of the following pairs: $$(\mathbf{1}, \mathbf{1}), \;\;\;\;\; (\alpha^2, \mathbf{1}), \\ (\alpha^4, \mathbf{1}), \;\;\;\;\; (\mathbf{1}, \beta^4), \\ (\mathbf{1}, \beta^8), \;\;\;\;\; (\alpha^2, \beta^4), \\ (\alpha^4, \beta^4), \;\;\;\;\; (\alpha^4, \beta^8), \;\;\;\;\; (\alpha^2, \beta^8). $$  Which of these are isomorphic?

Hopefully at this point my general question is clear.  First, in words:

> In considering semidirect products $G \cong H \rtimes K$ is there a (natural?) proof that shows the choice of generator(s) of $\mathrm{Aut}(H)$ affects the resulting group only up to the choice of 'non-equivalent' generators?

Here is a precise phrasing for which I would be thrilled to receive an answer:

> **Question:  Prove or disprove.**  Let $p$ and $q$ be primes such that $q$ divides $p-1$.  Consider semidirect products $G_\rho = \mathbf{Z}_p \rtimes_\rho \mathbf{Z}_q$ determined by group homomorphisms $$ \rho \colon \mathbf{Z}_q \to \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbf{Z}_p) \cong \mathbf{Z}_{p-1}. $$  Let $x$ multiplicatively generate $\mathbf{Z}_q$ and let $\alpha$ multiplicatively generate $\mathbf{Z}_{p-1}$.  Setting $n = (p-1)/q$ the generators for $\mathbf{Z}_q \subset \mathbf{Z}_{p-1}$ are $\alpha^{nk}$ where $k = 1, \dots, q-1$.  Let $\rho_k$ denote the group homomorphism determined by $x \mapsto \alpha^{nk}$.  Then $G_{\rho_k} \cong G_{\rho_\ell}$ for all $1 \leq k, \ell \leq q-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Dummit and Foote, Chapter 5, page 184:

> Assume that $K$ is a cyclic group, $H$ is an arbitrary group and $\phi_1(K)$ and $\phi_2(K)$ are conjugate subgroups of $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$. If $K$ is inifite assume $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are injective. Prove by constructing an explicit isomorphism that $H \rtimes_{\phi_1} K \cong H \rtimes_{\phi_2} K$ (in particular, if the subgroups $\phi_1(K)$ and $\phi_2(K)$ are equal in $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$, then the resulting semidirect products are isomorphic).

It even goes on to give a hint. (I strongly recommend spending a bit of time trying to do it yourself before reading the hint- it's a real spoiler.)

> Suppose $\sigma \phi_1(K) \sigma^{-1} = \phi_2(K)$ so that for some $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $\sigma \phi_1(k)\sigma^{-1} = \phi_3(k)^a$ for all $k \in K$. Show that the map $\psi:H \rtimes_{\phi_1} K \to H \rtimes_{\phi_2} K $ defined by $\psi(h,k)=(\sigma(h),k^a)$ is a homomorphism. Show $\psi$ is bijective by constructing a 2-sided inverse.

There's actually a lemma worth knowing here:

> Lemma: Let $a,m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $m$ divides $n$ and $\gcd(a,m)=1$. Then there exists $\overline{a} \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\overline{a} \equiv a \mod m$ and $\gcd(\overline{a},n)=1$.

There's a full explanation [here](https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/06/25/a-criterion-for-detecting-isomorphisms-among-semidirect-products-by-a-cyclic-group/) (this is where I first learned the lemma), but I welcome you to ask for hints rather than peak at the spoiler or answer.

Comment: Well this answer is everything I dreamed it would be, and more.  Thanks so much for the reference!  +1